# Is a surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ necessarily an injection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I guess my question is for every domain and codomain with the same infinite cardinality (though I do need a specific answer for $\mathbb{R}$). I know that the statement is true for finite sets, but I'm not sure about infinite sets.
Thanks

Comment: Given a set $X$, one possible definition of the statement "$X$ is infinite" is "The exists a surjection from $X$ to $X$ which is not injective" (technically, it's usually stated the other way around, but the difference is small, or even non-existent if you assume the so-called _axiom of choice_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily; as you say, it has to do with the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite. There are plenty of examples, for example you could take $f(x) = x^3-x$ or even
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \tan x & \text{if } -\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
or perhaps
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x \ge 0 \\ x+1 & \text{if } x<0 \end{cases}$$
I include the last example because it's very easy to prove that this function is surjective but not injective. Replacing the $+1$ by $-1$ gives you a function that is injective but not surjective.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are surjections from $R$ onto $R$ which are not injections. For example, the map $x\to x\sin x$.

Answer (score 2):

No, take for example $f(x)=x^3 - 2x$. Actually it's a characteristic property of infinite sets that they have surjections that's not an injection.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that  $\mathbb R  $ has the same cardinality as any interval $(a,b)$.  Thus there are bijections between the two.   Given such a bijection,  it would be easy to build a function which is surjective,  yet not one-to-one.   Just extend by sending any other point  (outside the interval ) to, well, any point...  That is,  extend any way at all...